# Django datetime validation Error?

Tags: python, django

I have a model where i want to raise error when user puts backdates in date_fields or enter earlier dates to today.

```
class Leave_Management(models.Model):
        employee = models.ForeignKey('employeeModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        reason = models.TextField(max_length=200)
        date_to = models.DateField(null=True)
        date_from = models.DateField(null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class LeaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leave_Management
        fields = ('__all__')
    def clean_date_to(self):
        date_to = self.cleaned_data.get('date_to')
        if not date_to > datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError('Enter Valid Date')
        return date_to
```

I tried to write this validation code But its showing error `TypeError at /home/leave
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.date'`

print(`date_to`) showing just `date 2018-06-2`

`print(datetime.date.today())` showing like this `datetime.date(2018, 6, 20)`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `date_to ` is None, It should be `datetime.date` Type

Comment: @Satendra sir ji but when i'm printing date_to, its showing the entered date!

Comment: try to enclose condition inside brackets  `if not (date_to > datetime.date.today()):`

Comment: @Satendra IT WORKED!!!!! sir ji thanks a lot.. 2 hours sey debug kar raha hun,nahi ho raha tha! btw can you explain why parenthesis changed the o/p!

Comment: Was it taking `not date_to` as whole? that's why NoneType o/p!

Comment: `if not (date_to > datetime.date.today()):` is evaluated the same as `if not date_to > datetime.date.today()`. It sounds like you had a different issue which you fixed.

Comment: @Alasdair But i just added parenthesis and it started working!

Comment: The `>` [has higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), so it will be evaluated first whether or not you have the parentheses. As I said, there must have been something else that you changed at the same time. Suppose that Python was doing `(not date_to) > datetime.date.today()` before. In that case, `(not date_to)` would be either `True` or `False`, so you wouldn't get the error *between instances of **'NoneType'** and 'datetime.date'*.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LeaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leave_Management
        fields = ('__all__')
    def clean_date_to(self):
        date_to = self.cleaned_data.get('date_to')
        if date_to < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError('Enter Valid Date')
        return date_to
```

just compare it `if date_to < datetime.date.today():`

instead of `if not date_to > datetime.date.today():`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem as per instruction of @Satendra i kept my `(date_to<datetime.date.get('date_to))` which in parenthesis, and it worked fine.